# I am just trying to build a simple snake game using python but its not changing its direction when its running

Tags: python, tkinter

so iam having trouble changing the direction when running the program. here is my program

```
from tkinter import *
import random

GAME_WIDTH = 600
GAME_HEIGHT = 600
SPEED = 100
SPACE_SIZE = 50
BODY_PARTS = 3
SNAKE_COLOR = "green"
FOOD_COLOR = "red"
BACKGROUND_COLOR = "black"



class Snake:
    def __init__(self):
        self.body_size = BODY_PARTS
        self.coordinates = []
        self.squares = []

        for i in range(0, BODY_PARTS):
            self.coordinates.append([0, 0])
        
        for x,y in self.coordinates:
            square = canvas.create_rectangle(x, y, x+ SPACE_SIZE, y+ SPACE_SIZE, fill= SNAKE_COLOR, tag="snake")
            self.squares.append(square)



class Food:


    def __init__(self):

        x = random.randint(0,(GAME_WIDTH/SPACE_SIZE)-1) * SPACE_SIZE
        y = random.randint(0, (GAME_HEIGHT/SPACE_SIZE)-1)* SPACE_SIZE

        self.coordinates = [x,y]

        canvas.create_oval(x,y,x + SPACE_SIZE, y + SPACE_SIZE, fill= FOOD_COLOR,tag="food")



def next_turn(snake,food):
    x, y = snake.coordinates[0]
    if direction == "up":
        y -= SPACE_SIZE

    elif direction == "down":
        y += SPACE_SIZE


    elif direction == "left":
        x -= SPACE_SIZE


    elif direction == "right":
        x += SPACE_SIZE
    

    snake.coordinates.insert(0, (x, y))

    square = canvas.create_rectangle(x, y, x + SPACE_SIZE, y + SPACE_SIZE, fill= SNAKE_COLOR)

    snake.squares.insert(0, square)
    
    del snake.coordinates[-1]

    canvas.delete(snake.squares[-1])

    del snake.squares[-1]



    window.after(SPEED, next_turn, snake, food)    
    


def change_direction(new_direction):

    global direction

    if new_direction == 'left':
        if direction != 'right':
            direction == new_direction

    elif new_direction == 'right':
        if direction != 'left':
            direction == new_direction

    elif new_direction == 'up':
        if direction != 'down':
            direction == new_direction

    elif new_direction == 'down':
        if direction != 'up':
            direction == new_direction


def check_collilsions():
    pass

def game_over():
    pass

window =Tk()
window.title('snake game')
window.resizable(False,False)
score = 0
direction = 'down'
label = Label(window, text="score:{}".format(score), font= ('consolas', 40 ))
label.pack()
canvas = Canvas(window, bg=BACKGROUND_COLOR, height=GAME_HEIGHT, width=GAME_WIDTH)
canvas.pack()

window.update()

window_width = window.winfo_width()
window_height = window.winfo_height()
screen_width = window.winfo_screenwidth()
screen_height = window.winfo_screenheight()

x = int((screen_width/ 2 ) - (window_width/2))
y = int((screen_height/2) - (750/2))

window.geometry(f"{window_width}x{window_height}+{x}+{y}")

window.bind('<Left>', lambda event: change_direction('left'))
window.bind('<Right>', lambda event: change_direction('right'))
window.bind('<Up>', lambda event: change_direction('up'))
window.bind('<Down>', lambda event: change_direction('down'))


snake = Snake()
food = Food()
next_turn(snake, food)


window.mainloop()
```

no idea what i did wrong .can anyone please help me

so the snake needs to change its direction after we run the program .when user press 'left' ,'right' , 'up', 'down' snake need to change direction corresponding to the key entered.

Comment: Change `direction == new_direction` to `direction = new_direction`

Comment: @Thingamabobs thanks mate.I am just a beginner couldn't find the error .Again thanks alot